# Input com caixa alta no Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Estou criando uma aplicação em `MVC` com `DDD` e nas minhas telas de cadastro, gostaria que os campos `string` como `NomeCompleto`, `Endereço`, `Cidade`, etc, fossem salvos em exibidos nos `inputs` em ***caixa alta***.

Eu não sei onde tratar isso pois tenho as classes do meu `domínio`, tenho as classes da minha `ViewModel` e tenho os `inputs` da minha `View` e tentei tratar um campo usando `text-uppercase`, mas, quando a minha `Controller` passa para a `ViewModel`, os dados ficam em minúsculas.

```
<input asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.NomeCompleto" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
```

***Resumindo:***

Como faço para tratar essa questão do lado do servido e do cliente? Suponho que eu teria que tratar isso nas minhas classes de `Domínio`, `ViewModel` e `inputs` da minha `View` correto?

```js
 public void Register(PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
        {            
            var registerCommand = _mapper.Map<RegisterNewPessoaCommand>(pessoaViewModel);
            Bus.SendCommand(registerCommand);
        }
```

```js
 public void Handle(RegisterNewPessoaCommand message)
        {
            if (!message.IsValid())
            {
                NotifyValidationErrors(message);
                return;
            }

            //Gerar inteiro aleatoriamente (Jalber)
            Random random = new Random();
            int id = random.Next(100, 3000);
            var pessoa = new Pessoa(id, message.PessoaNatureza);

            //Verificar o tipo de Pessoa (Física/Jurídica) antes de inserir no banco
            if (message.PessoaNatureza == ValueObjects.PessoaNatureza.Fisica)
            {
                var pessoaFisicaMessage = new RegisterNewPessoaFisicaCommand(message.PessoaFisica);

                if (!pessoaFisicaMessage.IsValid())
                {
                    NotifyValidationErrors(pessoaFisicaMessage);
                    return;
                }

                var pessoaFisica = new PessoaFisica(
                                                        pessoa.Id,
                                                        pessoaFisicaMessage.NomeCompleto,
                                                        pessoaFisicaMessage.Apelido,
                                                        pessoaFisicaMessage.DataNascimento,
                                                        pessoaFisicaMessage.Sexo,
                                                        pessoaFisicaMessage.EstadoCivil
                                                    );
                _pessoaFisicaRepository.Add(pessoaFisica);
            }
            else
            {
                var pessoaJuridicaMessage = new RegisterNewPessoaJuridicaCommand(message.PessoaJuridica);

                if (!pessoaJuridicaMessage.IsValid())
                {
                    NotifyValidationErrors(pessoaJuridicaMessage);
                    return;
                }

                var pessoaJuridica = new PessoaJuridica(
                                                            pessoa.Id,
                                                            pessoaJuridicaMessage.RazaoSocial,
                                                            pessoaJuridicaMessage.NomeFantasia,
                                                            pessoaJuridicaMessage.DataAbertura
                                                        );
                _pessoaJuridicaRepository.Add(pessoaJuridica);
            }

            _pessoaRepository.Add(pessoa);

            if (Commit()) //Se salvo, gravar o evento
            {
                //Passar uma pessoa (Física/Jurídica) para que a classe de evento carregue os campos necessários para o log
                var pessoaEvent = new Pessoa(pessoa.Id, pessoa.PessoaNatureza, message.PessoaFisica, message.PessoaJuridica);
                Bus.RaiseEvent(new PessoaRegisteredEvent(pessoa));                
            }
        }
```

```js
public class PessoaFisica : Entity
    {
        public string NomeCompleto { get; private set; }
        public string Apelido { get; private set; }
        public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; private set; }

        public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; private set; }
        public virtual Sexo Sexo { get; private set; }
        public virtual EstadoCivil EstadoCivil { get; private set; }

        public PessoaFisica() { }

        public PessoaFisica(PessoaFisica pessoaFisica)
        {
            NomeCompleto = pessoaFisica.NomeCompleto;
            Apelido = pessoaFisica.Apelido;
            DataNascimento = pessoaFisica.DataNascimento;
            Sexo = pessoaFisica.Sexo;
            EstadoCivil = pessoaFisica.EstadoCivil;
        }

        public PessoaFisica(string nomeCompleto, string apelido, DateTime? dataNascimento, Sexo sexo, EstadoCivil estadoCivil)
        {            
            NomeCompleto = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nomeCompleto) ? nomeCompleto.ToUpper() : nomeCompleto);
            Apelido = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apelido) ? apelido.ToUpper() : apelido);
            DataNascimento = dataNascimento;
            Sexo = sexo;
            EstadoCivil = estadoCivil;
        }

        public PessoaFisica(int id, string nomeCompleto, string apelido, DateTime? dataNascimento, Sexo sexo, EstadoCivil estadoCivil)
        {
            Id = id;
            NomeCompleto = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nomeCompleto) ? nomeCompleto.ToUpper() : nomeCompleto);
            Apelido = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apelido) ? apelido.ToUpper() : apelido);
            DataNascimento = dataNascimento;
            Sexo = sexo;
            EstadoCivil = estadoCivil;
        }


        public PessoaFisica(int id, Pessoa pessoa, string nomeCompleto, string apelido, DateTime? dataNascimento, Sexo sexo, EstadoCivil estadoCivil)
        {
            Id = id;
            Pessoa = pessoa;
            NomeCompleto = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nomeCompleto) ? nomeCompleto.ToUpper() : nomeCompleto);
            Apelido = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apelido)? apelido.ToUpper() : apelido);
            DataNascimento = dataNascimento;
            Sexo = sexo;
            EstadoCivil = estadoCivil;
        }

        public PessoaFisica(Pessoa pessoa, string nomeCompleto, string apelido, DateTime? dataNascimento, Sexo sexo, EstadoCivil estadoCivil)
        {
            Pessoa = pessoa;
            NomeCompleto = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nomeCompleto) ? nomeCompleto.ToUpper() : nomeCompleto);
            Apelido = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apelido) ? apelido.ToUpper() : apelido);
            DataNascimento = dataNascimento;
            Sexo = sexo;
            EstadoCivil = estadoCivil;
        }
      
    }
```

Comment: essa classe `CSS` só muda o visual, mas, o que você precisa realmente é gravar em maiúsculo, como o contexto por trás é maior e a gente não sabe como você grava no banco de dados fica complicado, você poderia colocar um exemplo de atualização da sua base, é nesse momento é que eu faria a gravação em caixa alta.

Comment: O processo é feito com várias classes. Usei um modelo do Eduardo Pires... Como exemplo, tenho uma classe Pessoa no meu Domínio e outra classe RegisterNewPessoaCommand que é parecida com uma viewmodel, só que a utilizo para receber os dados da ViewModel  e carregar minhas classes de domínio para só então gravar no repositório... Voute tentar postar um breve resumo do código...

Comment: Eu pensei em tratair isso nas classes poco do meu domínio...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção seria fazer pelo domínio

Exemplo:

```
public class PessoaFisica
{
    private string _nomeCompleto;
    private string _apelido;
    public string NomeCompleto { get => _nomeCompleto; set => _nomeCompleto = value.ToUpper(); }
    public string Apelido { get => _apelido; set => _apelido = value.ToUpper(); }
}
```

Desta forma, independente do usuário salvar em **minúsculo**, sempre será **caixa alta** e como estará salvo em **caixa alta** no banco, o retorno também será assim.

Comment: Por que não auto-inicializar as propriedades com `{ get; set; }` ?

Comment: Porque eu modifiquei o `set` para sempre retornar os textos em caixa alta

Comment: Obrigado @Barbetta!